# Can I mix dual-rank and single-rank ram for my Dell XPS 15 9750 laptop

Tags: laptop, memory, dell-xps

I want to upgrade the ram for my dell xps 15 9750 which is now 8gb ram (2x4gb). I buyed 16gb (ddr4 2666 dual-rank) ram.

Is it possible to mix single-rank (4gb ddr4 2666) and dual-rank (16gb ddr4 2666) together ???

If I mix this together, is there any risk for my laptop ????

Thank you in advances

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is apparently possible, but of course not guaranteed to work.

The Crucial RAM website lists as proposed upgrades for
[Compatible Memory for Dell XPS 15 (9570)](https://www.crucial.com/usa/en/compatible-upgrade-for/Dell/xps-15-(9570))
both dual and single ranked RAM, so the motherboard will accept both

However, having two dissimilar RAM sticks will at least certainly disable
[dual-channel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-channel_memory_architecture)
mode on memory access which can double the bandwidth on memory access.

So technically, it's possible, but there is no guarantee it will run and run nicely.

It is highly recommended to buy RAM in a kit rather than mix and matching.
And if you mix and match, try to get the exact same modules that are in your
computer already to enable dual-channel.
Just to stress the point, even mixing and matching two exact same kits may not work
for enabling dual-channel.